# is there a broadcast message when the alarm goes off?

Tags: android, broadcast, alarm

Do we have any kind of broadcast message when alarm goes off in Android? I couldn't find one. When the alarm goes off, I'd like to start my apps.

EDIT: It's the build-in alarm.

Comment: Do you mean alarm from Alarm Application or your application alarm.?

Comment: it's the build-in alarm

Comment: If it's in your app then you can specify the pending intent. Refer: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html